# SQL Server CE ORM

Tags: sql, database, orm

For my solution I use SQL Server CE. 
I want to use an ORM for rapid database access. 
Can you give me a hint? 
I tried subsonic 3.0 and LinqToSql, but both seem not to support SQL Server CE.

Thanks, 
Radu D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try Entity Framework 4.0, here is the CE 4.0 download for http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate supports SQL Server CE.

http://blog.yodersolutions.com/2008/12/getting-started-with-nhibernate-and-sql-compact-edition/

http://www.haugern.net/blog/sql-server-ce-up-and-running-with-nhibernate-nant/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at LightSpeed - http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed - it supports SQL CE 3.5 and 4.0.